# Create plots similar to weather storm broadcasts

Tags: matlab, animation, matlab-figure

I am trying to create some plots using MATLAB that would resemble how weather networks display their storms moving through an area, like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=335TNgX2pXI).

I have 1000 (X,Y) coordinates and an associated storm warning value `[X Y StormValue]`. The range of `StormValue` is between `0:10` so I would like to create a `colorbar` for this range and then plot each (X,Y) coordinate with the associated color from the `colorbar` in a 2D plot. I know how to create 3D `mesh` and `surf` plots, however I am curios if there is an easy way to do this type of 2D plotting in MATLAB.

Eventually I would like to create an animation as I have `StormValues` for 1 minute for all 1000 (X,Y) points, however I do not even know where to begin. Any help or advice on what to look at in MATLAB to do this would be much appreciated.

Comment: `doc image` for the plot and `doc getframe` for the animation should get you going.

Answer (score 2):

You can stack all your storm warning values in a matrix (eg. matrix `img`) where `img(i,j)` is the value corresponding to `x=j` and `y=i`, and then use the function `contourf` like:

```
contourf(img, 10) %// Being 10 the number of levels
```

To display it sequentially you can stack all your values in an array having as many layers as 'frames'. Where `img(i,j,k)` is the value corresponding to `x=j`, `y=i` and `frame=k`. You could simply use a for loop:

```
s_per_frame = 0.3 %// seconds per frame
for i=1:size(img,3)
    contourf(img(:,:,i), 10);
    pause(s_per_frame);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

For the plots, just create a 2d matrix for each image frame (`x` and `y` being the `stormvalues`, as you have it). Then you want to map the intensity of each value to a different color, you can start by using the standard jet colormap in range of your minimum to maximum stormvalues (10)

```
c_map= jet(10);
```

Then show it using image

```
image(your_2D_matrix);
axis off;
colormap(c_map);
colorbar;
```

Then, as @dasdingonesin suggested, use `getframe` to take a grap of the image, save it and then you animate through refreshing your figure with each frame.

Comment: user2840470 asked the question, I'm the one who suggested `getframe` ;)